# AWSMobileClient: signalTokensNotAvailable System.err: java.lang.Exception: No cached session

Tags: android

When I tired to send the IdToken to api using below code but  AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens().getIdToken().getTokenString() gives below error when token expires.
try {
headers.put(AUTHORIZATION, Constants.BEARER_TAG + AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens().getIdToken().getTokenString());
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
2022-09-16 16:41:08.584 4737-4782/ W/AWSMobileClient: signalTokensNotAvailable
2022-09-16 16:41:08.584 4737-4782/ W/System.err: java.lang.Exception: No cached session.

I need to send the activeIdToken whenever the api call happens. Please help me out.